# how to define the process of retrieving data from sqlite programmatically?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im new to these sqlite accessing programming.i have 9 edittext and coded to store values in sqlite db...next time if i insert the same value in first edittext the remaining value should display without entering..code below is what i have tried but couldnt get back the values

```
//this is my dbhandler class method

> public Data findProduct(String phone) {       String query = "Select *
> FROM " + TABLE_FEEDBACK + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PHONENO + " =  \"" +
> phone + "\"";
>               SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

> ```
>           Data data = new Data();
>           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {             cursor.moveToFirst();           data.setPHONE(cursor.getString(0));
>       data.setName(cursor.getString(1));
>       data.setFood(cursor.getString(2));
>       data.setService(cursor.getString(3));
>       data.setCleanliness(cursor.getString(4));
>       data.setExperience(cursor.getString(5));
>       data.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
>       data.setEmail(cursor.getString(7));
>       data.setBirthday(cursor.getString(8));
>       data.setAnniversary(cursor.getString(9));
>       data.setFavrestaurant(cursor.getString(10));
>       data.setFavstaff(cursor.getString(11));
>       data.setFavdish(cursor.getString(12));
>       data.setSuggestion(cursor.getString(13));
>       data.setReturn(cursor.getString(14));           cursor.close();         } else {
>       data = null;        }
>       db.close();         return data;    }
> ```
>
> > ```
> > /*public void openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {   
> >
> >     //Open the database       
> >     String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;      
> >     db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);     
> >     }  */
> > ```
>
> ```
> //this is my mainactivity method
> ```
>
> > ```
> > public void lookupProduct (View view) {
> >      DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
> >
> >      Data data = 
> >       dbHandler.findProduct(phonenumber.getText().toString());
> >
> >      if (data != null) {
> >        name.setText(String.valueOf(data.getName()));
> >        address.setText(String.valueOf(data.getAddress()));
> >   } else {
> >          name.setText("No Match Found");
> >   }            }
> > ```

Comment: Building a query string like this is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this worked by defining the method in dbhandler class and calling them in main activity

```
public Data findProduct(String phone) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_FEEDBACK + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PHONENO + " =  \"" + phone + "\"";
    System.out.println("this is the product >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Data data0 = new Data();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        data0.setPHONE(cursor.getString(0));
        data0.setName(cursor.getString(1));

        data0.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
        data0.setEmail(cursor.getString(7));


        cursor.close();
    } else {
        data0 = null;
    }
    System.out.println("data set value :>>>>>>>");
        db.close();
    return data0;
}
```

and this the mainactivity code under on click()

```
EditText phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              String phonenmbr = phonenumber.getText().toString();
              Data data0 = dbHandler.findProduct(phonenmbr);
if (data0 != null) {
                 phonenumber.setText(String.valueOf(data0.getPHONE()));
                 customername.setText(String.valueOf(data0.getName()));
                 customeraddress.setText(String.valueOf(data0.getAddress()));
                 customeremail.setText(String.valueOf(data0.getEmail()));



          } else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter other details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
```